# Multiple mouseup's using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to simulate multiple mouseup's but it only works the first time:

definition of the event handler:

```
$(".list").mouseup(addCompanyEditServiceOnClick);
```

function that handles the event:

```
function addCompanyEditServiceOnClick(e)
{
    // action that moves an element from a list to another
}
```

function that simulates the mouseup's:

```
function loadCompanyEditExistingServices()
{
    var services = $("#ServiceIds").val();
    var arrServices = services.split(",");

    for (i = 0; i < arrServices.length; i++)
    {
        $("#element_" + arrServices[i]).mouseup();
    }
}
```

It only does the mouseup the first time, why?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What is the value of `$("#ServiceIds").val()`? Are there spaces after commas?

Comment: Hi, an example is "1,2,3,4" that represent the part of the element ID ("#element_1" / "#element_2" / etc) to be moved from a list to another by mouseup